# Невозможно преобразовать const char в char

Tags: c++

Программа которая заменяет каждую букву в тексте на букву которая идет после нее в алфавите через n символов. При компиляции выдает ошибку невозможно преобразовать const char * в char* (ругается на input_text)

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *input_text;
    char *output_text;
    input_text = "bla bla";
    int n = 5;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; input_text[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        count++;
    }
    int input_text_lenght = count;
    output_text = new char[input_text_lenght];
    for (int k = 0; k < input_text_lenght; k++)
    {
        output_text[k] = input_text[k] + n;
    }
    cout << "input_text ... " << input_text << endl;

    cout << "output_text ... " << output_text << endl;
    delete[] output_text;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не "const char в char", а "const char * в char *" в строчке `input_text = "bla bla";`. Разумеется, невозможно. Компилятор все правильно сказал. Учитесь пользоваться `const`.

Comment: @AnT, да вы правы. Не подскажете где ошибка в программе, ибо на выходе получается output_text ... gqf%gqf¤¤¤¤▌▌▌▌▌┴╤.▌. А должны просто символы на следующие поменяться

Comment: У вас нет замыкающего `\0` в строке-результате. Вы даже памяти для него не выделили.

Comment: Да, нету, но если добавить то все равно почему-то дописывает лишние символы в результате

Comment: Так не бывает. Нам отсюда не видно что вы там и как "добавили". Видимо, неправильно добавили.

Comment: Извиняюсь, а куда правильно добавить замыкающие `\0`

Comment: Последним символом в строке `output_text` должен быть `\0`. В конец строки добавить - потому он и называется "замыкающим".

Comment: Подскажите, как добавить этот символ в конец?

Comment: @AnT, все разобрался, спасибо

Comment: В общем-то это против правил использования данного языка (С++), но если очень хочется (или просто в самом деле надо в какой-то ситуации), то поможет простейшее приведение типа `input_text = (char *)"bla-bla-...";` (с таким компилятор соглашается)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> char *input_text;
> ```

```
const char *input_text;
```