# Отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора

Tags: c++, visual-studio

**Ошибка в классе Puma -> Puma.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Puma.h"

Puma::Puma(
    char* noise,
    bool nv,
    int w,
    char* stat,
    bool life,
    int nk,
    float h
) : Wild(noise, nv, w, stat, life, nk), height(h)
{

}

Puma::Puma() : Wild("vovhik", true, 3, "q", false, 66), height(2)
{

}

void Puma::print()
{
    Wild::print();
    std::cout << "Длина: " << height << std::endl;
}
```

**Класс Wild (Puma - сын Wild)**

```
#pragma once

#include "Wild.h"

Wild::Wild(char* noise, bool nv, int w, char* stat, bool life, int nk) : Cat(noise, nv, w), alive(life), num_kill(nk)
{
    //std::strcpy(sound, noise);
    std::strcpy(status, stat);
}

void Wild::print()
{
    Cat::print();
    std::cout << "Статус: " << status << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Живой: " << alive << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Количество убийств: " << num_kill << std::endl;
}
```

**Wild.h**

```
    #pragma once

#include <iostream>

#include "config.h"
#include "Cat.h"

class Wild :
    public Cat
{
protected:
    char status[STRING_SIZE];
    bool alive;
    int num_kill;
public:
    Wild(char*, bool, int, char*, bool, int);
    virtual void print();
};
```

**Puma.h**

```
    #pragma once
#include "Wild.h"
class Puma :
    public Wild
{
protected:
    float height;
public:
    Puma();
    Puma(char*, bool, int, char*, bool, int, float);
    void print();
};
```

Comment: В Puma.cpp ошибка в строчке:
Puma::Puma() : Wild("vovhik", true, 3, "q", false, 66), height(2).
По моему - всё верно передаю.

Comment: А где сам код, при компиляции которого возникает сообщение об ошибке? В какой строке?

Comment: [Невозможно преобразовать const char в char](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/900561/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-const-char-%d0%b2-char)

Comment: @Harry:
1>Puma.cpp
1>C:\Users\hodar\source\repos\cat_family\cat_family\Cat.h(12,28): warning C4305: инициализация: усечение из "int" в "bool"
1>C:\Users\hodar\source\repos\cat_family\cat_family\Puma.cpp(16,20): error C2664: "Wild::Wild(Wild &&)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "const char [7]" в "char *"
1>C:\Users\hodar\source\repos\cat_family\cat_family\Puma.cpp(16,21): message : При преобразовании из строкового литерала теряется квалификатор (см. /Zc:strictStrings)
1>C:\Users\hodar\source\repos\cat_family\cat_family\Wild.h(16,2): message : см. объявление "Wild::Wild"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После комментария с уточнением - так это потому, что вы объясняете, что вы в своем конструкторе **будете менять** передаваемые строки. А сами, наверное. передаете строковые литералы, которые менять нельзя...

Понимаете, если вы пишете

```
Wild::Wild(char* noise,
```

это значит, что вы планируете менять строку `noise`, и нельзя создавать что-то типа

```
wild w("aaa", ...);
```

Это относится ко всем вашим `char *`.

Надо, раз вы будете менять, примерно так...

```
char s[] = "aaa";
wild w(s, ...);
```

Можно, конечно, просто прочесть, что такое квалификатор `const`, и конструктор писать как

```
Wild::Wild(const char* noise, ...
```

Какой путь вам больше нравится - тот и выбирайте...

Comment: Я просто очень мало понимаю в программировании, хоть и делаю курсовую :D
Выживаем как можем :)
Не посоветуете книгу какую-нибудь? :)
Большое спасибо) правда, очень благодарен)

Comment: Смотрите [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263/228791).